# Azure Function Timeout after 30 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have set up an Azure Function v3. Configured with Standard plan per this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout. Also, set up functionTimeout to Unlimited

Is Standard **(S1:1)** plan the right one? Do I need to change it to P1V12 in order to be able to set it to 'unlimited' timeout?

[image]
[image]
**host.json:**

[image]

**Keeps crashing after 30 minutes:**
[image]

It's as if host.json is not being considered? or is the plan not correct? Please help.

Comment: What does your function do? Is it running a loop and doing work for 30 minutes?

Comment: given a range of dates, it's downloading listings from MLS service, at times it may longer than 30 min

Comment: I would split that function in two or more, one that creates QueueItems and then another function that triggers on one QueueItem and then you can maybe split the downloading and the processing to another queue with items. That way you can keep the runtime for each single function down without having to push the boundaries of the functionTimeout. Even on a premium plan you only get 60 minutes guaranteed, even if you configured it with "-1"

Comment: The function will not run past 60 min. Is my plan correct?, should it be "standard"?

Comment: Are you  sure `-1` means unlimited? What about zero (`0`) ?

Comment: documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout says -1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this to work is to add an attribute:

```
[Timeout("05:00:00")]
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
```

Seems host.json file is being ignored

EDIT - **Fix with HOST.JSON file**

Found this thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/81

Solution:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/34#issuecomment-596781972

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var tempServices = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var azureFuncConfig = tempServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddConfiguration(azureFuncConfig)
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var configReader = configBuilder.Build();
            var config = configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
            {
                Client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(new AzureServiceTokenProvider().KeyVaultTokenCallback)),
                Vault = configReader["keyvaulturl"],
                Manager = new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager()),
            }).Build();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
        }
```